# How to minimize the page in the property sheet?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have used property sheet concept and display 3 dialog box on the property sheet.

Now to access the each dialog i have to clicked on the tab of each dialog.

But my need is that i want to minimize the first dialog and show the second dialog without using tab. for that i have added one button using that button i minimized the first dialog but when i tried to call the second dialog i get assertion failed error. i have done like this...

In the 1st dialog (.cpp) file :

```
void ClstdemoDlg::OnBnClickedMinimize()
{
    ClstdemoDlg_1 dlg; // created 2nd dialog variable.
    this->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE); // minimize the 1st dialog
    dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); //Tried to show 2nd dialog but get Assertion failed Error
}
```

Please let me know how to do this?

Comment: So minimizing works, but opening the second dialog doesn't? If so, your title is rather misleading.

Comment: Sounds like you may want a "wizard" property sheet?  Otherwise, I'm rather confused about your design.